# Swift 3/4 -Fill data in desired tableView cells only

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, dictionary, indexoutofboundsexception

I am populating my tableView with dynamic JSON data. I have designed custom tableviewCell where, I am hiding a view and showing only when data is present. Firstly I have show all employees names in the tableView, later when they are assigned any project, then I have to show project details in that DetailsView shown as below. 
[image]

Here I have called projectDetails api in a forLoop for employeeIds in EmployeeList.
I am storing the project details in an array and assigning the values to the rows by `projectListArray[indexPath.row]` in *cellForRow*. But the problem is, when some employees are not assigned any project, then I get **Index out of range** error. `ExpandableCell` will remain collapsed. Hope I am clear till here.

So only the employees who have been assigned projects will show the `ExpandableCell` expanded, for others, the cell will be collapsed.

```
    public func getEmployeesList(request : EmployeesListRequest) {      // api call to get Employees List

        // if EmployeeListArray is not till and if response is SUCCESS, give ProjectDetails api call 

     if response.isSuccess() {
         for beds in array {
            self.getProjectDetails(request: self.projectDetailsRequest)
            //refresh TableView 
        }
    }                     
}

public func getProjectDetails(request : ProjectDetailsRequest) {

    if Network.response(response: response, errorMsg: nil) {
        let object = response.obj as? ProjectDetails                 
            if response.isSuccess() {
                if response.obj != nil {
                    self.projectDetailsArray.append(object!)
                    self.projectEmployeeIdArray.append(object.employeeId!)
                 }else{
                     print(“Project Object is nil\n")
                }
                }
            }
    }

// In cellForRowAt indexPath
// Displayed Employee names in NamesView now want to display project details
var expandedRows = Set<IndexPath>()
for id in projectEmployeeIdArray {
            if employeeId == id {
                cell.projectDetailsView.isHidden = false
                expandedRows.insert(indexPath)

                if !projectDetailsArray.isEmpty{
                        let sortedData = projectDetailsArray.sorted(by:{$0.employeeId < $1.employeeId})   //since the dictionary was not sorted. //Error if some ids nil
                    let details = sortedData[indexPath.row]             //Error because some employees do not project assigned.

                    cell.projectLabel.text = details.projectName!

                }else{                                        
                    expandedRows.remove(indexPath)
            }
        }
    }
```

I had also tried `projectDetailsArray[safe: indexPath.row]`, but it failed to assign project project details. If index 0 and 2 would have project details, it would give nil data for index 2.

Output desired:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest to create a model of your data, something like

```
struct Employee {
    var id = ""
    var name = ""
    var projects = [Project]()
}

struct Project {
    var name = ""
}

var model = [Employee]()
```

If you have this, you need convert your JSON-Response into the Employee/Project Model in a sorted way you like. This only has to be done once and not in each and every `cellForRowAt indexPath` call

The implementation of the `UITableViewDataSource` functions is quite straight-forward:

- in `numberOfSections(in:)` return the number of employees in `model`
- in `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`, get the employee of the given section, and return the count of it's projects
- in `tableView(_:titleForHeaderInSection:)`, get the employee of the given section and return it's name (or whatever you want to be displayed here)
- in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`, get the employee of the given `indexPath.section`, get the project of that employee according to `indexPath.row` and configure the cell